# In Matlab code, (X~=1).*Y. How to stop executing Y when x~=1 fails?

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a piece of code for my thesis and comes to the following problem.

In creating `ksubgrid`, if the first logical part fails, e.g. there are elements in `reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)` equals to 1, MATLAB reports an error since the first vector in `linspaceNDim` has a vector with column number 0.

How do I let MATLAB stop doing `linspaceNDim` when the logical fails? I know that if I do an element-by-element loop, the if statement can solve the problem. But since number of loops is large here, it's gonna be slow.

So how to solve the problem in matrix?

```
ksubgrid=reshape((reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)<nk & reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)>1 ).*...
linspaceNDim(kgrid(1,reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)-1),kgrid(1,reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)+1),nksub)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply split up the computation into two segments?  Compute `X`, check for whatever you want, then if it passes, then compute `Y`?

Comment: You're right. For simplicity, I deleted the rest of ksubgrid definition. So the full one is   ` ksubgrid=reshape((reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)<nk & reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)>1 ).*...
 linspaceNDim(kgrid(1,reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)-1),kgrid(1,reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)+1),nksub)+...
 (reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)<nk & reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)==1 ).*...
 linspaceNDim(kgrid(1,reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)),kgrid(1,reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)+1),nksub)` In this case, the trick you mentioned seems not feasible...

Comment: Problem solved. I combined the logical statement into the indexing of kgrid:  `ksubgrid=reshape(...
     linspaceNDim(kgrid(1,(reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)-1).*(reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)>1)...
     +reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1).*(reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)==1))...
     ,kgrid(1,(reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)+1).*(reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)<nk)...
     +reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1).*(reshape(kmax_ind,nz*nb*nk*nxi,1)==nk)),nksub),[nz,nk,nb,nxi,nksub]);'

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that code is doing... but I'm glad you figured it out!